# Fetching values returned by functions from Free Marker template in Java

Tags: java, function, freemarker

How can I get the value returned by a function in Free Marker Template and use it in Java?

This is the code I'm using in FMT:

```
<#function avg x y>
  <#return (x + y) / 2>
</#function>
${avg(10, 20)}
```

How can I use this function in Java?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? FM is for displaying the view. Anything available to FM would have been available to Java before the view is created. However, if it is a web app then you can pass the data base as part of a form post. The other option is to attach an object to your model and then call a method of that object in FM. I depends on what exactly you are try to achieve. Can you give any more details?

Comment: @Goose If I want to fetch the global variables declared in FTL and use those in java, how can I do that?

Comment: @Goose /i have this function in FTL
<#function avg nums...>
  <#local sum = 0>
  <#list nums as num>
    <#local sum = sum + num>
  </#list>
  <#if nums?size != 0>
    <#return sum / nums?size>
  </#if>
</#function>
${avg(10, 20)}
${avg(10, 20, 30, 40)}
${avg()!"N/A"}

which returns avg of numbers. Avg will be calculated in Ftl only and I dont have it in java. for storing this value in database, i'll first need to fetch it in java then write a code to store it to database. so how do i fetch the values in java?

Comment: It depends where you are getting your numbers from (10, 20, 30 etc.). If they are hard coded in the FTL then why does it need to be calculated. If they are not hard coded then where are the original number generated? I presume in the Java code calling the view. Either way they should be available in the model that is passed to FM. It's difficult for me to give a better answer without more details.

Comment: @Goose: Can u just tell, is there any way by which we can access the values in java? I know it's redundant to do this.. bt i have been told to search so. so posted. I am very new to Free Marker language. have just started studying it.

Comment: You could attach an object with a method like String returnValue(String value) to the model. Return an empty String "". In FM you can then call this method ${objectName.returnValue("20")}. I will not add this as an answer because I strongly advise against it.